# MacBook Pro (15" Retina): Where are all the LCI stickers located?

Tags: macbook-pro, repair, damage

How many [Liquid Contact Indicator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_contact_indicator) stickers are inside a [MacBook Pro (15" Retina)](http://www.apple.com/mac/compare/results/?product1=macbook-pro-retina-15&product2=macbook-pro-retina-15)?
Where are they all located?

Comment: You checked the iFixit teardown?

Comment: Nope. Didn't think there was one for this model.